# db architechture of a time sheet application in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As I am reading the rails 3 way I wanted to make a small app that will help me learn along with the book.  I am thinking of making a simple timesheet application in rails, however, I can't figure out where to start as far as calendar functionality goes. This is what I have so far.

```
User has_many Timesheets

Timesheet belongs_to user
```

Timesheet will have `date:datetime`, `hours:datetime` and `comments:string` attributes.

how can I map a whole month to the timesheet?

For example.

if the user wants to fill timesheet for `06/01/2011 - 06/07/2011` will he have seven rows in the Timesheet table?

I would like someone to explain a brief architecture of ActiveRecord for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would at least start out with something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timesheets
end

class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :work_days
end

class WorkDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timesheet
end
```

`Timesheet` will have a `user_id:integer` attribute.

`WorkDay` will have `day:date`, `hours:integer`, `comment:text`, and `timesheet_id:integer` attributes.

Then you can create timesheets with any collection of individual workdays you wish.

The form for a WorkDay could look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @work_day do |f| %>
  <%= f.label(:timesheet, 'Timesheet') %>:
  <%= f.collection_select(:timesheet_id, Timesheet.all, :id, :name) %><br />
  <%= f.label :day, 'Date' %>:
  <%= f.date_select :day %><br />
  <%= f.label :hours, 'Hours worked' %>:
  <%= f.text_field :hours %><br />
  <%= f.label :comment, 'Comments' %>:
  <%= f.text_area :comment %><br />
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to create a new WorkDay with all of its attributes and attach it to any existing Timesheet.

Note: This will look for a `name` method in Timesheet, which you could implement like this, for example:

```
def name
  "Timesheet ##{self.id}"
end
```

Comment: thanks but how would I create 7 forms of `WorkDay`. Thats my problem.  Should I create attributes like `day1:date, hours1:integer...day7:date, hours:integer` instead? Or can you tell me how would a simple form_for work for this model?

Comment: You don't need different forms of WorkDay. The `day:date` field contains this information. The form_for would be very simple. I'll add an example to my answer.